# Ubuntu 11.10, FF 11, ATI Catalyst v12.2, Driver Package version 8.95, WebGL doesn't work

Tags: 11.10, ati, webgl

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, FF 11, ATI Catalyst v12.2, Driver Package version 8.95,  WebGL doesn't work.

This is a pretty capable setup and definetly did have FF work previously, Note: I've downloaded and installed the ATI drivers from AMD. Not sure how to get WebGL working.

#### Updated

My video card info:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Cypress [Radeon HD 5800 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ATI Technologies Inc Device 0b00
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fbee0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at fbec0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
    Kernel modules: fglrx, radeon
```

Comment: _This is a pretty capable setup_ Can you please add more information to your question, we need to know your system and your graphics card to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to get WebGL working by passing the `aticonfig --initial` command in the terminal. This is an installation step for the driver that I have initially missed.

Answer (score 1):

From a week of mindnumbing research on this matter (as it does affect me as well), webGL implementation under the Catalyst 12.2 drivers are either: A) Blacklisted somewhere else rather than the normal locations (i.e. about:flags) or B) Blacklisted for ATI x86_64 devices across the board.  This would mean that Chrome devs need to change some code in default configuration outside of what is editable by users.  I CAN seem to get webGL working in Firefox 11, but framerate is less than half of what I was getting in Chrome.  I will say that after trying xorg-edgers latest gpu drivers (665 fps) vs. ati catalyst 12.2 fglrx(760 fps), I have seen quite an increase in framerate, and I really don't want to go back until I see evidence that xorg-edgers is comparable, but the functionality is definitely lacking ATM for certain applications.  I just wanted to throw commiserating information out there in hopes that more people might be able to spark interest in a fix.

I tried aticonfig --initial  but the line didn't help the problem, even after reboot.  I used the code to ignore the blacklist for hardware also, but with no success.  I also changed about:flags in Chrome to the best possible configuration with no success.
Is there anyone out there that has been able to solve this issue?